# "LIBEAY32.dll" , "libpcre-1.dll"and "zlib1.dll" Errors using CMake

Tags: dll

I wanted to install OpenCV 3 in windows 10, with MinGW compiler and codeblocks IDE. But when I use CMake to build libraries, and push configure button, I get these three errors sequence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open source software packages often depend on other open source libraries rather than directly using the Windows- or macOS-proprietary APIs on those platforms. So when working with open source software, most people use "package managers" that automatically download and install all the open source dependencies. It looks like OpenCV has dependencies on open source crypto (EAY = OpenSSL), regex (PCRE = Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), and compression (zlib) libraries.

If you really want to do this by hand, you could download and install all those dependencies, and their dependencies, etc.

Comment: Thank you!
Are there package managers for openCV that I can use for installing all dependencies automatically?
Cause I tried OpenSSL light installer, but the LIBEAY32.dll error didn't solve!

Comment: @Hasani package managers generally aren't per-package. You run one package manager on your system to manage *all* of your open source packages. On Windows, cygwin is a longstanding open source package manager. So if I were you, I'd install cygwin and use cygwin to install OpenCV (honestly if I were you I suppose I wouldn't be trying to install OpenCV from source, I'd just be using the premade Windows binary installers :-).

Comment: I did install cygwin and tried to install those dll files with it, but wasn't successful!